# MySql copy parent / child tables while keeping foreign key references

Tags: mysql

I need some ideas how to copy parent and child table while keeping foreign key references between them. I have parent table media and child table paths. Rows in paths belong to rows in media referenced by media_id. So I need to duplicate all rows from media (into same media table) and duplicate all rows from paths (into same paths table) WHILE keeping media_id references.

```
table.media

id primary AI

55
56
77



table.paths

id PRIMARY AI | media_id FOREIGN references table.media.id

0            55             
1            55
2            55
3            77
```

Comment: I am asking is there a standard method of copying the record in A, and, at the same time copying all the records from B that relate to A. Is it a stupid question, unclear or what?

Comment: It is not a stupid question; I just don't understand which part of it you are having problems with. Standard way would be to create new tables, copy the data, enable foreign keys. Hope this makes sense

Comment: There are no new tables. I said duplicate into the same tables with newly primary keys of course.

Comment: I thought I misread that. You can't duplicate the data if your tables have primary keys. That's just not possible in RDBMS world.

Comment: One would expect a method that duplicates rows plus auto resuming primary keys, strange that something like this doesnt exist.

Comment: It is possible to do what you want if your auto increment fields are your only unique fields, but you will need staging tables and no other users may use these tables while you do the diplication.

Comment: Yes, primary AI keys are only unique, however I would like to do this without columns in queries if posible (so copy whole row, and null ID).